# For Anaconda, if I haven't created a virtual environment, which environment am I in?

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I've installed Anaconda2 on Ubuntu 14.04. And I added an extra line

```
export PATH=/home/usr/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

in the .bashrc. And typed `$ source .bashrc`. Then now which/what environment am I in for Anaconda? It's quite confusing.

More specifically, if I haven't created a virtual environment, which environment am I in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before creating any environments you are just using the set of packages that installs with Anaconda, which is the root environment. In order to start using an environment you would first create it with `conda create -n new_env ...`, where new_env is your environment name and ... Is a list of packages you need.  Once creating an environment completes you would then start using it by typing `source activate new_env`.  See the env documentation:  https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env.html.

Comment: To create a new environment, the command is `conda create -n new_env packages` not `conda env create ...`. The latter command is used to make an environment from a file.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question (technically). When you haven't activated an environment yet, you're in the `root` environment.

Comment: @darthbith thanks for keeping me honest.  I'm going to blame just waking up, answering questions before having my morning coffee is a bad idea.

Comment: @JeremyFarrell Thanks for your answer. I have two more questions related to the above.

1. So the root environment in not a virtual one?
2. Do all the packages installed in the root environment naturally transfers to a virtual environment that I create?

Comment: @julypraise I do not think the root environment is a virtual environment.  It is just a starting set of standard packages.  Packages installed in the root environment do not transfer to newly created environments.  However, the packages installed in root will be available in the package cache such that you will not have to re-download any packages that you already have for new environments.